# Binding value on input text in react native doesn't let me write anymore

Tags: ios, reactjs, input, react-native

I got the following input text on a Child Component:

```
 <Input 
     placeholder={ i18n.t('searchSomeone') }
     value={ this.props.searchText }
     onChangeText={ this.props.onSearch }
     defaultValue={''}/>
```

This is the way , I'm passing the variable and onChangeText handler:

```
<ChildComponent 
         onSearch={ this._onSearch }
         searchText={ this.state.searchText }>
</ChildComponent>
```

And this is the `_onSearch()` function:

```
componentWillMount: function() {

        this._onSearch = _.debounce((text) => {
            this.setState({ refreshing : true }, () => {
                if(text.length === 0) {
                    this.setState({ filteredSearch: false }, () => {
                        this.getAllReports();
                    })
                }else{
                    this.setState({
                        page: 1,
                        refreshing: true,
                        reports: [],
                        filteredSearch: true
                    }, () => {
                        this.getReportsBySearchString();
                    })
                }
            })
        }, 1000);

    },
```

I wanted to bind this input text value, because when I do a `pull up to refresh`, i just want to set the text to empty string.

```
_onRefresh: function() {
    this.setState({
        filteredSearch: false,
        searchText: ''
    }, () => {
        this.getAllReports();
    })
},
```

But the problem is that with this implementation, whenever I try to type in the text input, it doesn't type anything.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not saving the input value in `this.state.searchText`. That's the reason why the input value is always `''`.

```
this._onSearch = _.debounce((text) => {
        this.setState({ 
            refreshing : true,
            searchText: text // <-- Here
        }, () => {
            if(text.length === 0) {
                this.setState({ filteredSearch: false }, () => {
                    this.getAllReports();
                })
            }else{
                this.setState({
                    page: 1,
                    refreshing: true,
                    reports: [],
                    filteredSearch: true
                }, () => {
                    this.getReportsBySearchString();
                })
            }
        })
}, 1000);
```

Edit

You can try debounce the callback function you are passing to `setState`, it is not tested so I'm not sure if it is going to work.

It should be something like this

```
this._onSearch = (text) => {
            this.setState({ 
                refreshing : true,
                searchText: text
            }, this._callback)

this._callback = _.debounce(() => {
    const text = this.state.searchText;
    if(text.length === 0) {
                  ...
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing i tried, but I don't know why whenever I start typing, only 1 letter of the entire stuff that i typed is set into the input text at once, and I have to wait those 1000 milliseconds of the _debounce to update the input and show the new value. Do you know why? It's not fluid, not inserting all the text as I type.

Comment: it seems like you don't need that `debounce` there, why don't you remove it? `this._onSearch = (text) => {...}`

Comment: Yea, I added that _debounce to avoid calling a fetch every time i type a character. That wouldn't be very performant.

Comment: Yea, without the _debounce i noticed it works. But any suggestion on how can I delay my fetches then to prevent from being called every 1 millisecond while typing? wouldn't that be a problem in the future?

Comment: you can try to debounce the callback function you are passing to `setState`, let me edit my answer

Comment: Ohhhh good catch, I think i know what you're saying, just add a _.debounce( () => { my function here } , 1000) right?

Comment: yeah something like that!

Comment: kk let me check :)

Comment: Oh btw, if you have some free time and knowledge about fetch_blob module for react-native, can you take a glance at this inconvenience that i have? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44050839/how-to-send-multiple-data-at-once-using-fetch-blob-react-native Thanks in advance for your help :)